# How to set existing, unstaged, uncommitted subdirectory as submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Sometimes, I clone a 3rd party project from github as a subdirectory in a project, instead of doing `git submodule add <repourl>`, but after doing some work I realize that I want to make it a submodule after all.

How can I mark an existing subdirectory that has never been committed as a submodule without loosing my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to:

- move your current subrepo folder (rename it)
- add your submodule:

  ```
  git submodule add -- /url/repo
  ```
- add your changes back:

  ```
  cd repo
  git checkout abranch
  git --work-tree=../repo.renamed add .
  git commit -m "add work"
  git push -u origin abranch
  ```
- don"'t forget to record the new SHA1 of that repo:

  ```
  cd ..
  git add repo (# no trailing slash)
  git commit -m "record new sha1 for repo"
  git push
  ```